# An Unintentionally Recursive Sub

Tags: vb.net

One of my Subs repeats numerous times and I don't know how to handle it.

On my MainWindow I have a status bar that contains several Labels that should show the local time in countries around the world.  Here is the computation for one of the labels:

```
Private Sub PopulateStatusBar()
Dim UTCTime As Date = Date.UtcNow

Dim timezone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time")
Dim localtime As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCTime, timezone)
AtlanticLabel = " Atlantic" & localtime.ToString("ddd HH:mm") & " "
....
End Sub
```

This routine calls itself until it serendiptiously calculates the samve value for UTCTime two times in a row.  To investigate this problrm, I put Debug.WriteLine(UTCTime) in line XXX and it repeated itself 77 times before ending.  The problem is that it keeps recalculating UTCTime every time it needs that value.

Here are the steps I have talken to resolve the issue.

STEP 1:
I removed UTCTime entirely and simply put the it's calculation into the formulas where it is used.  This did not solve the problem.

STEP 2:
I removed all three local variables (UTCTime, timezone and localtime) and dropped the calculations directly into the AtlanticLabel line making one very long, ugly piece of code.  This did not solve the problem.

STEP 3:
I did even more drasticc surgery to end up with this:

```
Private UTCTime As Date
Private timezone As TimeZoneInfo
Private localtime As Date

Private Sub PopulateStatusBar()
    UTCTime = Date.UtcNow
    timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time")
    localtime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UTCTime, timezone)
    Go()
End Sub

Private Sub Go()
    AtlanticLabel = " Atlantic" & localtime.ToString("ddd HH:mm") & " "
....
End Sub
```

This did not solve the problem.

Apparently, whenever UTCTime is used, it goes back to the source code (UTCTime = Date.UtcNow) whereever it might be by calling the Sub that contains it.  Essentially PopulateStatusBar is recursive under the hood.

I have no idea how to fix this.

**Added In response to Dr.Null**

Here is how PopulateStatusBar gets called.

1. In my Application Class

   ```
     Private Sub Main(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        ....
        Dim win As New MainWindow
        win.Show()
    End Sub
   ```
2. In MainWindow

   ```
    <Window
        x:Class="MainWindow"
        ....
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadMe}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        ....
    </Window>
   ```
3. In the MainWindow View Model

   ```
    Public Class MainWindowVM
            ....
            Private ReadOnly Property _LoadMe As New RelayCommand(AddressOf PerformLoadMe)
            Public ReadOnly Property LoadMe As RelayCommand
                Get
                    Return _LoadMe
                End Get
            End Property
            Private Sub PerformLoadMe()
                Dim tmr As New System.Timers.Timer With {.AutoReset = True, .Enabled = True}
                AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf PopulateStatusBar
                PopulateStatusBar()   <----Called Here
            End Sub
   ```

Comment: "until it serendiptiously calculates the samve value " <- why? Can you change that test / condition?

Comment: You forgot to show the `PopulateStatusBar` caller. Is it a `Timer.Tick` event? loop? else?

Comment: I tried your original PopulateStatusBar code added a debug.writeln to show AtlanticLabel (with seconds). Then added a delay of 5 seconds and recalculated LocalTime and AtlanticLabel again from the original UTCTime. The second code created exactly the same output, so UTCTime is not being recalculated when you use it.  Your issue lies elsewhere

Comment: Nothing shown could cause a recursive loop.

Comment: @dr.null  Yes.  See the details in my addition to the OP

Comment: @dbasnett  I thought the same when I wrote the code but when I stepped through it line-by-line it kept calling itself.  However, dr.null's comment suggests he's on to the problem.  I'm anxious to see his next comment.

Comment: @dr.null  I added .Interval = 1000 to the line that instantiates the Timer.  Sadly, that did not solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure this is actually a recursive thing?  Also can't see any recursion there.  But does look to me that you're calling the PopulateStatusBar method directly in the PreformLoadMe() as well as on the timer elapsed event.  Maybe a breakpoint in PopulateStatusBar and check the callstack to confirm

Comment: @Hursey  I've done that and watched as I went step-by-step  through the code.  You can literally see it jump back to the beginning of the subroutine while it is still in it.

Comment: Did you look at the call stack though?  See where these calls are coming from

Comment: Make sure the `PerformLoadMe` is being called just once, otherwise new timers are created, new event handlers all of which call the `PopulateStatusBar` and the result is the problem here. Put a break point at the mentioned method to see how it's being called. You just need one timer and one event handler. Also, the `System.Timers.Timer` should be a class field, it implements the `IDisposable` interface and should be disposed of when you close/dispose its container.

Comment: Just in case, see also [Timer.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject?view=net-7.0).

Comment: @dr.null  Yes, the problem did arise out of calling PopulateStatusBar to both initialize the status bar and to update it.  I separated the two routines, did some cleanup and all is well.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as such.

Comment: Well done and good luck.